# Delete duplicates from table (List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList ...)

Tags: java

I got table like

```
List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<>()
```

Where List's within are table rows, i need to set all duplicate values ALL OVER THE TABLE to null, how can do it via only ArrayList && foreach loop || λ - expressions?

Must work somehow like this:

```
1   2   3               null    2   3           
4   1   5       ->      4   null    5    
1   6   9               null    6   9
```

Sorry for my poor English and thank you for fast response!

Comment: Do you want to set the reference to `null` or remove them? A simpler way of doing this is to have a `Set<List<Integer>>` which will implicitly drop any duplicates. Do you want to remove duplicate rows or values?

Comment: Lets say the first list in `table` holds integer `Integer(1)`, and third list also holds such an object: do you want to null both objects or only objects that follow the first "unique" one?

Comment: Do you want to keep the table the same size? Same number of rows and entries per row?

Comment: @PeterLawrey how is the hashvalue for `List<Integer>` computed and compared in between `List<Integer>` members of the `Set`? E.g., how will a set `{ [1, 3], [1, 4] }` define what duplicate _inner_ list values are? (Pardon the syntax, I'm just getting started with Java, asking out of curiosity!)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Added example how this must work:/

Comment: A double iteration should do the job, first you look for elements that need to be "nulled" then you do the "nullation" using the found elements

Comment: Your example does not help. Do you want to change `null` to `1`? What does this have to do with "i need to set all duplicate values ALL OVER THE TABLE to null"?

Comment: @RC. Could you please write down some examples?

Comment: @LutzHorn Example fixed

Comment: Sure: first iteration 1 => put in some seen list, 2 => put in some seen list, 3 => put in some seen list, 4 => put in some seen list, 1 => already in seen list, put in nullToBe list, etc then second iteration:  1 => in nullToBe list, replace by null, 2 => not in nullToBe list, keep as is, etc

Comment: OK. Now please explain what you mean by "duplicate" exaclty. Is `1` a duplicate because the *table* contains more than one `1` *anywhere*? And please [edit] your question and add the code you have tried so far. Does it work?

Comment: @LutzHorn "is 1 a duplicate because the table contains more than one 1 anywhere?" - Yeah, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Using java-8,

```
//Find duplicates
Map<Integer, Long> counts = 
    table.stream()
         .flatMap(Collection::stream)
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->i, Collectors.counting()));

// and remove them
table.stream().forEach(row -> row.replaceAll(i-> counts.get(i) > 1 ? null : i));
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the (slightly unclear) question as a deduplication (removal rather than "nulling"):

```
List<List<Integer>> dedup = table.stream().distinct().collect(toList());
```

or java 7:

```
List<List<Integer>> dedup = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(table));
```

which is generally more useful.

However, if nulling is *really* required:

```
Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
List<List<Integer>> dedup = table.stream()
  .filter(list -> set.add(list) ? list : null)
  .collect(toList());
```

The `add()` method of a Set returns `true` is adding the element changed the set - ie if it's an element not seen before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this approach is to build an index map for all the elements present in the `List` and setting the value to `null` if more than one value found for a key

```
    List<List<Integer>> table = new ArrayList<>();
    table.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    table.add(Arrays.asList(4, 1, 5));
    table.add(Arrays.asList(1, 6, 9));

    System.out.println("Before " + table);

    Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> indices = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < table.get(i).size(); j++) {
            int el = table.get(i).get(j);
            if (indices.get(el) == null) {
                indices.put(el, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            indices.get(el).add(Arrays.asList(i, j));
        }
    }

    indices.keySet().stream()
                    .filter(k -> indices.get(k).size() > 1)
                    .flatMap(k -> indices.get(k).stream())
                    .forEach(li -> table.get(li.get(0)).set(li.get(1), null));

    System.out.println("After  " + table);
```

output

```
Before [[1, 2, 3], [4, 1, 5], [1, 6, 9]]
After  [[null, 2, 3], [4, null, 5], [null, 6, 9]]
```